# Naxsi - blacklist and whitelist setup with Nginx

Tags: nginx

Opened this issue:

> https://github.com/nbs-system/naxsi/issues/486

But is seems not to be active there.

I am using in my project currently **modsecurity** to filter out bad IPs and allow good ones:

Something like this:

```
modsecurity_rules '
      SecRuleEngine On
      SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatchFromFile /etc/modsecurity/whitelist.txt" id:1,phase:1,allow
      SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatchFromFile /etc/modsecurity/blacklist.txt" id:2,phase:1,deny,status:429,msg:\'blacklist\'
```

What would be the best approach to add this functionality to NAXSI?

Should I add a Rule or modify the code? Can you give some tips on either one, both or none, when this is not possible (are there any performance implications or implications in general)

Any other possibility to achieve this goal in NGINX setup?

Tried this approach:

```
############################
## Block rules: 1700-1800 ##
############################

MainRule "str:1.1.1.1" "msg:IP Blacklist" "mz:$HEADERS_VAR:X-Forwarded-For" "s:$BLACK:8" id:1701;
MainRule "str:2.2.2.2" "msg:IP Blacklist" "mz:$HEADERS_VAR:X-Forwarded-For" "s:$BLACK:8" id:1702;
```

Where 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 will be IP I want to block (from Blacklist) - I will generate the `config/list` daily.

However, I still don't know how to whitelist some IPs, so that they will never be blocked (through block rules but also through other rules). Any ideas?

Was thinking about Whitelist rule for all:

```
MainRule wl:0 "mz:$HEADERS_VAR|X-Forwarded-For:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
```

BUT it is also not a valid rule ....

What approach would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think for this purpose you could use [ngx_stream_access_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_access_module.html) module.

You could create two lists and include them to your projects nginx config file. 
For example:

```
include /path/to/file/blacklist.conf
include /path/to/file/whitelist.conf
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a question, is adding up modules in nginx a good practice? I wanted to keep modsecurity and add naxsi, but was advised to use only one module. I the case of ngx_stream_access_module, I will also end up with 2 modules. The latter being possibly smaller than modsecurity. Any advice on this on performance? Or is it only maintainability question

Comment: Also just realized.... Naxsi can still block ip from whitelist, no? Or how will it know about the list?